# Counting string(s), getting an empty set, why? (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, string, csv

Good morning, I am trying to count the number of times 'yes' and 'no' appear in a column in a csv document. For some reason, I am getting an empty set in the final output. The formatting is produced in the final document as directed, but the count and set are empty. here is the code:

```
yes = 0
no = 0
with open('2021FASTSurveyResponses.csv', 'r') as fastout:
    yayornay = csv.reader(fastout)
    next(yayornay)
    for yesno in yayornay:
        yesno = yesno[1]
        # pattern1 = re.compile(r"no")
        # pattern2 = re.compile(r"yes")
        # pattern1.split(',')
        # pattern2.split(',')
        # yesno.split(',')
        yesno.strip()
        print(yesno)


    for line in yesno:
        if line == 'yes':
            # yes.count('yes')
            yes.append()
            # yes = yes + 1
            # yes += 1

    for line in yesno:
        if line == 'no':
            # no.count('no')
            no.append()
            # no = no + 1
            # no += 1

    # datetime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    # with open('yayornay.csv', 'w') as f:
    #     f.write('Yes(s) = {} /'.format(yes))
    #     f.write(' No(s) = {} '.format(no))
    #     f.write(datetime)
```

I think the solution is easy, but something is not connecting for me here. what am I missing?
thank you in advance

Comment: `yes += 1` should be causing an error. Assuming it's not, that means `if line == 'no'` and `if line == 'yes'` are never true. Double check what `line` is. `print(list(line))` will help show hidden characters. And, instead of `+=`, use the `append` lines that you have commented out.

Comment: Taking a look at the commented out line about yes.append() and no.append(). I commented out 'in life =' and uncommented out yes/no.append() - but this results in the same issue... I will test the print(list(line)) next

Comment: Yes, note the first half of my comment. The second part of my comment was once you had fixed the first issue

Comment: yep, looking at that now. thank you

Comment: The lines you get from `.readlines()` will end with a newline character (except perhaps the very last line).  It is therefore impossible for them to be equal to `"yes"` or `"no"`.  You should apply `.strip()` to each line, to get rid of the newline and any other extraneous whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

initialise yes and no as integers (0) instead of array ([]) if you want the count.

Replace

```
no = []
yes = []
```

with

```
no = 0
yes = 0
```

Comment: That is probably closer to what they want. As I mentioned in a comment though, they should have gotten errors with their original approach, and the fact that they didn't means that code is never executing, so this won't change anything until that's fixed.

Comment: Well, this is getting crazy: nothing I try seems to be working for me to count the existence of 'yes' or 'no'

Comment: See Jason Harper's comment. Print out "line" and see why it's never equal to yes or no

Comment: Yeah, I can see that from the opening the of the file, and extracting only the column from the csv I want, that each line is being included as 'yes' or 'no' and as type=str. I am not sure how to then populate the for loop to go over those values. It should be simple.

Comment: Also, if I just run print(yesno.count('yes')) that I am seeing 1 where that string exists, and then 0 when 'yes' does not exist.

Comment: thank you everyone, I just moved over to pandas and got it finished. cheers all